# How to make a div scrollable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-scrollable

I have only one list div and I want to make it scrollable. I have seen scrollpane examples, it's great but I am looking for an smaller simpler alternative.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: have you already written some code to see? Are you trying to scroll an <ul> inside a shorter <div>?

Comment: Maybe try the smallest and simplest solution: css `overflow: auto;` combined with fixed height or width.

Comment: @fcalderan Yeah <ul> inside a <div>

Comment: @pawel I also get a greyed out horizontal scroll which messes other elements on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think you need jquery, just add style="overflow:auto;" to the div.

Answer (score 1):

> For Future readers ...

If `jQuery` is must then you can do this by :

```
// Any one accordingly ...

$('#yourIdForDiv').attr('overflow','auto');
$('#yourIdForDiv').attr('overflowy','scroll');
$('#yourIdForDiv').attr('overflowx','auto');
```

Comment: If you'd like to overflow without jquery, keep in mind you can also specify the x&y axis using `"overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:auto` as an example. Note the "-" as a difference from the jQuery property.